# Alternative Ways to Earn Reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, policy, moderators

What are ways to earn reputation other than "Good" Questions and Answers that do and do not require time and effort for a moderator on each [action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) on Physics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort and the subject is [thoroughly explained in the help centre](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: "do not strain moderators" Generally, following the rules doesn't strain them.

Comment: The +2 from an accepted edit soes not require a moderator, just >2k two members

Comment: The short of it is that reputation is on offer on every area that helps the site, and that is why reputation is on offer there. The only such action that requires additional vetting (suggested edits from <2k members) only feeds a review queue handled by >2k members (i.e. not moderators), which is why there is a rep cap there (with the rep cap indicative of how much editing becomes a strain). Currently the suggested edits queue has ≤2 edits in it at any one time.

Comment: On the other hand, it brings a lot more strain to the site to keep bringing unresearched questions to this Meta.

Comment: A small script to make sure everyone reads the rules in big letters and a test awarding 500 rep for passing would help.

Comment: We [already have that](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/121/informed). And we politely inform newcomers as to where they can find further information. After several such pointers, though, we do sort of expect them to go and do some digging.

Comment: New users need more of an in your face do not pass until completed format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> that do and do not require time and effort for a moderator on each action on Physics?

Let's talk about way to *not* make unnecessary work for the moderators.

The first and foremost thing to do is to pay attention to how *your* flags are resolved. Click on the "helpful flags" test in your profile.

[image]

Every time a flag is declined you're being told that the moderator who processed it thought you were wasting their time. If you're doing a good overall job of flagging your helpful flags will outnumber your declined ones by a significant factor.

Beyond that, stop adding bad or out-of-place content.

- Every comment posted as an answer is flagged and most come to a moderator's attention.
- Every answer that doesn't come anywhere even close to answering a question gets flagged and most of those come to a moderator's attention.
- Every question without a clear physics question gets flagged and most come to a moderator's attention.
- Every question so garbled that the average reader has no idea what it's about generates flags and most come to a moderator's attention.
- Every time someone posts three or four badly written variants of the same questions generates flags which come to a moderator's attention.
- Every time someone flags a question because they want it re-opened they are directly making work ***and*** it won't help them because we expect the review queue to take care of that.